# Industries that thrive in crisis like COVID 19

Tags: macroeconomics, supply-and-demand

I am aware that some industries thrive during crisis times like COVID 19...Food supplies, medical, counselling, funeral services, liquor etc.

Are there any other industries that may do well during these testing times?

Answer (score 2):

In no particular order:

- Consumer Staples: household goods, food, beverages, hygiene products, and other products that individuals are either unwilling or unable to eliminate from their budgets even in times of financial trouble
- IT: Internet/Social Media, Software, and Semiconductors.
- Healthcare: Anything that involves the provision and coordination of medical and related goods and services. Not to mention, small biotech companies.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by NinjaGaiden:

- Delivery services, enabling consumers to receive goods at home while under lockdown.
- Suppliers of videoconferencing technology, enabling businesses and other organisations to hold virtual meetings (see [here](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2020/mar/31/zoom-booms-as-demand-for-video-conferencing-tech-grows-in-coronavirus-outbreak)).
- Legal and other firms advising on drafting of wills (see [here](https://www.ft.com/content/7025f425-87c2-4738-b305-6392d13ce0c0))