# What are the Industries and sectors who performs better during COVID?

Tags: markets

Maybe I'm a bit late with this question, but I just want to list all the sectors who benefit in these covid times.

My current list is

1. cure researchers
2. food delivery
3. tech companies overall
4. especially tech the ones like zoom which we people actively use working from home

Who else benefits?

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome! There is a similar question with some partial answers from 8 months ago: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/35929/24728. The situation has evolved since, some new data has arrived, so I think your question is on time